Equivalence of Sobolev norms for smooth functions with compact support
Let $f\in C^\infty_c([0,1]^n)$, then we can extend it to a $1$-periodic smooth function $\tilde f$. We define the fourier transform (series) of $f$ ($\tilde f$):$$
\hat f(\xi):=\int e^{2\pi i x\cdot \xi}f(x)\,dx,\quad \mathcal F\tilde f(\tau):=\int_0^1 e^{2\pi i\tau\cdot x} f(x)\,dx$$
for $\xi\in \mathbb R^n$, $\tau\in \mathbb Z^n$. Let $s>0$, we define the Sobolev norms by $$ \|f\|_{H^s(\mathbb R^n)}^2:=\int_{\mathbb R^n} (1+|\xi|)^{2s} |\hat f(\xi)|^2\,d\xi,\quad \|\tilde f\|_{H^s(\mathbb \Pi^n)}^2:=\sum_{\mathbb Z^n} (1+|\tau|)^{2s} |\mathcal F \tilde f(\tau)|^2\,d\tau.$$
Under the condition $f\in C^\infty_c([0,1]^n)$, can we show that the two norms above are equivalent? (This holds obviously when $s$ is a positive integer.)

Since it holds for integers, you should be able to use the theory of interpolation spaces to deduce it for general s.

@MichaelRenardy The problem is: the two spaces above are not only characterized by Fourier transform/series, but also be closures of $C_c^\infty([0,1]^n)$ with respect to the norms, so I'm not sure if they're still the complex interpolation spaces.
